# Stock prediction + news sentiment with SVM in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, prediction, sentiment-analysis

I would like to predict the stock prices and news sentiment score together with SVM in R, in order to see whether news have an impact on stock price and their prediction. I read that support vector machines (svm) are a good machine learning approach for this problem. I have one column that represents the date of the stock and news, one column represents the stock prices on that day and 4 columns which represent the sentiment scores based on different lexica. I would like to test first with one of that lexica and if the models works, trying on the other. The dataset is included below. I found some examples with python but couldn't found something for R. I like to use the `svm()` function from the `e1071 package`

I split the data into train and test set:

```
sample <- sample(nrow(sentGI),nrow(sentGI)*0.70)
df.trainGI = sentGI[sample,]
df.testGI = sentGI[-sample,]
```

And I tried already this SVM code, but my wrong prediction rate is 100

```
plot(df.trainGI$GSPC.Close, df.trainGI$SentimentGI, pch = 19, col = c("red", "blue"))


svm_model_GI <- svm(SentimentGI.Class ~ ., df.trainGI)
print(svm_model_GI)

plot(svm_model_GI, df.trainGI)


svm_pred_GI <- predict(svm_model_GI, newdata = df.testGI, type="response")
rmse <- sqrt(mean((svm_pred_GI - df.testGI$GSPC.Close)^2))
rmse
```

What I am doing wrong here? Hope somebody can help me!

[Dataset](https://ufile.io/81pnj199)

Answer (score 1):

You're using model accuracy to evaluate the model. Accuracy is used for classification problems but your response variable is continuous. You should use RMSE.

```
pred <- predict(radial.svm, newdata=df.test, type='response')
rmse <- sqrt(mean((pred - df.test$GSPC.Close)^2))
rmse
```

Continuation from comments:

[image]

The first plots GSPC.Close against date (left) and the second plots SentimentGI against date (right). Notice that stock prices generally increase over time whereas sentiment has a slope of 0 in that same time frame. What does that tell you?

Comment: thank you for your response wisamb. I tried your code but getting and rmse of 1816.42. I change the class of my classification column into numeric so that the prediction code works. But I guess something works wrong. I updated my code I used and also the dataset I used, maybe you have an idea.

Comment: If I change my `SentimentGI.Class` column into factor I can print the svm classification and it seems that its working good, but the prediction code is than not working. geting an error that `"-" not meaningful for factors`

Comment: And I also need to calculate the accuracy in order to see with what kind of percentage it is possible to predict stock prices based on financial news. Researcher always calculated that measure.

Comment: Now you are solving a different problem. You need to decide what your response variable is. For example in your new code, you have the response variable as `SentimentGI.Class` as a categorical variable so you wouldn't use RMSE, which is for continuous variables. Also, you are comparing `SentimentGI.Class` against `df.testGI$GSPC.Close` while calculating RMSE. Lastly, how did you get `SentimentGI.Class`? If it's from `SentimentGI` then your model with `SentimentGI.Class ~ .` needs to exclude this variable. Decide which question you are trying to answer, sentiment score or stock price?

Comment: You are really helping me a lot and I really appreciate. I got `SentimentGI.Class` from `SentimentGI`. I checked with the `summary function` what is the median of `SentimentGI` and based on that I decided all `values < the median` are `0` and all greater `1`. But if my idea was wrong we could do it different, i am just very new in this field and dont know that much. I want to answer this question: Stock price prediction based on financial news. So I want to see how high is the accuracy for stock prediction when news articles (based on sentiment scores) are included.

Comment: So you're response variable is `GSPC.Close` which is continuous, so you would use RMSE. When I run the code with your original data table, I get an RMSE of about 570. This number is compared with RMSE of other models to see which is the smallest. RMSE indicates how far your predicted values are from the line of best fit. The smaller the RMSE the closer those values are to the line of best fit. Check out the two plots in my answer above.

Comment: thanks wisamb for your answer and your plots. But what do you want to tell me with them? I didnt understood the idea behind it. Is it correct how I run my SVM?